# Wildfly-11, Java and Spring framework: Could not autowire. No beans of 'JMSContext' type found

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jms, wildfly

I'm trying to implement JMS based on quickstart helloworld-mdb in existing project. 
I have following class, which is using in controller:

```
@Repository("FrameQueue")
public class FrameQueue {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8314035702649252239L;

@Inject
private JMSContext context;

@Resource(lookup = "java:/jms/queue/MyRequestQueue")
private Queue queue;
private JMSConsumer consumer;
private JMSProducer producer;
...
}
```

When I'm not using annotation for FrameQueue, then I can't inject FrameQueue in controller's class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/my")
public class MyController {

    @Resource
    private DataService dataService;

    @Resource
    private FrameQueue frameQueue;
    ...
}
```

I also tried to directly @Inject JMSContext in controller's class, but it results in the same "Could not autowired.." error.
I'm using WildFly-11.0.0 with configuration of standalone-full.xml in standalone.xml.
I have beans.xml in webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

How can I correctly inject JMSContext for an application using Spring framework?

My server configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">
            <server name="default">
                <security-setting name="#">
                    <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
                </security-setting>
                <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </http-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                    <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
                </in-vm-connector>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </http-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                    <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
                </in-vm-acceptor>
                <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                <jms-queue name="MyRequestQueue" entries="queue/MyRequestQueue jms/queue/MyRequestQueue java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/MyRequestQueue"/>
                <jms-queue name="testQueue" entries="queue/test java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test"/>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
            </server>
        </subsystem>
```

Comment: What does your server configuration look like?

Comment: Hello James, I have updated question with server configuration.